# React doesn't re-render when updating array in redux reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

I have an array in reducer initial state. I am passing it to the component, and I am moving an element of array to the different index inside an array in reducer only by dispatching an action from the component. I am able to see the changes in the array, but it is not re rendering on the screen.

```
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes'
import _ from 'lodash'

const initialState = {
    columnDefs: [
       { key: 'a', name: 'Order', width: 120},
       { key: 'b', name: 'Supplier'width: 100},
       { key: 'c', name: 'Article', width: 100}
    ]
}

export default function reduce (state = initialState, action = {}) {
   case actionTypes.UPDATE_COLUMNS: {
      let columnDefs = _.cloneDeep(state.columnDefs)
      columnDefs.splice(
        action.data.columnTargetIndex,
        0,
        columnDefs.splice(action.data.columnSourceIndex, 1)[0]
      )
      return { ...state, columnDefs }
  }

  default:
    return state
}
}
```

Component dispatches the action with source index and target index.

```
  onUpdate (source, target) {
      const columnSourceIndex = this.state.columnDefs.findIndex(
         i => i.key === source
      )
      const columnTargetIndex = this.state.columnDefs.findIndex(
         i => i.key === target
      )
      this.props.updateColumns({columnSourceIndex, columnTargetIndex})
  }
```

Inside component's render

```
    <DraggableContainer onHeaderDrop={this.onUpdate}>
        <ReactDataGrid
            columns={this.state.columnDefs}
            rowGetter={rowGetter}
            rowsCount={_rows.length}
            rowHeight={40}
            onRowClick={this.props.onRowClick}
            emptyRowsView={NoDataView}
            onGridRowsUpdated={this.handleGridRowsUpdated}
        />
    </DraggableContainer>
```

The connected component

```
      function mapStateToProps (state, ownProps) {
        const { columnDefs, selectedRows } = state.FOL
        return ({ columnDefs, selectedRows })
      }

      function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
        return ({
          updateColumns: (data) => { dispatch(updateColumns(data)) }
        })
      }

      export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FOLContainer)
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rinkesh

Comment: What does the component look like?

Comment: I am using react-data-grid module.

Comment: I've already encountered this kind of issue and I solved my problem using `componentWillReceiveProps(props)` and try to `console.log(props)`

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see your connect function.

Comment: I am receiving the updated props un componentWillReceiveProps as well as in render method also

Comment: @Andrew Sorry for delayed response.
I have edited the question with connect function.

Comment: it looks like you are using the columnDefs from state, rather than the new ones you receive in componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: I am passing columnDefs to my unconnected component from the connected component and storing it in the state of unconnected component. and I also update the state from componentWillReceiveProps method.

Comment: Why are you storing it in the state of the unconnected component?  I would just render the props I receive.  That duplication of state frequently leads to bugs like this.

Comment: Initially, I tried it with the prop only, but it was showing the same problem. So I changed it to the state.